# Idiomatic Rust method for handling references to a buffer

Tags: reference, rust

I would like to be able to construct objects that contain immutable references to a mutable buffer object. The following code does not work but illustrates my use case, is there an idiomatic Rust method for handling this?

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Parser<'a> {
    buffer: &'a String
}

fn main() {
    let mut source = String::from("Peter");
    let buffer = &source;
    let parser = Parser { buffer };

    // How can I legally change source?
    source.push_str(" Pan");

    println!("{:?}", parser);
}
```

Comment: Aa @Ijedrz pointed out, this does not work without using either interrior mutability or unsafe code. Both are things I would not recommend unless you are really expierenced in using rust. In 95 % of cases there are more ideomatic solutions which are quicker and safer. Once I am at home I will probably write an acual answer in case noone else does this for me

Comment: At this point, the only idiomatic solution I can think of that does not use either interior mutability or unsafe code is to pass an immutable buffer reference as a parameter to the Parser when invoking a Parser method. This strikes me as a bit awkward though...

Comment: Another idea would be to have one struct containing both the string and and a vec of parser closures. While this probably requires a complete rewrite it should quite fast/ideomatic. Or in case you only need to add items to the buffer, this could be safely written using a wrapper containimg a ´UnsafeCell<String> which only enables a the ´push_str()´ method and one getter method which returns a ´&str´ of the current length. Both approaches would be completely safe. *--written on mobile,sry*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what exactly you want to achieve by mutating the `source`; I would assume you don't want it to happen while the parser is doing its work? You can always try (depending on your specific use case) to separate the immutable from the mutable with an extra scope:

```
fn main() {
    let mut source = String::from("Peter");

    {    
        let buffer = &source;
        let parser = Parser { buffer };

        println!("{:?}", parser);
    }

    source.push_str(" Pan");
}
```

If you don't want to use `RefCell`, `unsafe` (or to simply keep a mutable reference to `source` in `Parser` and use that), I'm afraid it doesn't get better than plain refactoring.

Answer (score 2):

The golden rule of the rust borrow checker is: Only one writer OR multiple readers can access a resource at a time. This ensures that algorithms are safe to run in multiple threads.

You breach this rule here:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Parser<'a> {
    buffer: &'a String
}

fn main() {
    // mutable access begins here
    let mut source = String::from("Peter");
    // immutable access begins here
    let buffer = &source;
    let parser = Parser { buffer };

    source.push_str(" Pan");

    println!("{:?}", parser);
    // Both immutable and mutable access end here
}
```

If you are sure that your program doesn't actively access resources at the same time mutably and immutably, you can move the check from compile time to run time by wrapping your resource in a `RefCell`:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Parser {
    buffer: Rc<RefCell<String>>
}

fn main() {
    let source = Rc::new(RefCell::new(String::from("Peter")));
    let parser = Parser { buffer: source.clone() };

    source.borrow_mut().push_str(" Pan");

    println!("{:?}", parser);
}
```

If you plan on passing your resource around threads, you can use an `RwLock` to block the thread until the resource is available:

```
use std::sync::{RwLock, Arc};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Parser {
    buffer: Arc<RwLock<String>>
}

fn main() {
    let source = Arc::new(RwLock::new(String::from("Peter")));
    let parser = Parser { buffer: source.clone() };

    source.write().unwrap().push_str(" Pan");

    println!("{:?}", parser);
}
```

---

On another note, you should prefer `&str` over `&String`

Comment: Your answer is as I expected but is this really idiomatic Rust? Using a shared reference is a common C++ solution...

Comment: Isn't that exactly what you are trying to achieve, though? Maybe I understand your question wrong. If not a shared reference, what is it you're trying to do?

Comment: Would you mind elaborating? Maybe then I am able to come up with something better.

Comment: @GearoidMurphy `Arc`'s are shared references. A `RwLock` or `Mutex` can provide the ability to temporarily lock the resource while it's being read/written to. It has a cost, but this is the safest solution.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on how this can be done unsafely, what you've described can be achieved by using a raw const pointer to avoid the borrowing rules, which of course is inherently unsafe, as the very concept of what you've described is pretty unsafe. There are ways to make it safer though, should you choose this path. But I would probably default to using an `Arc<RwLock>` or `Arc<Mutex>` should safety be important.

```
use std::fmt::{self, Display};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Parser {
    buffer: *const String
}

impl Display for Parser {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        let buffer = unsafe { &*self.buffer };
        write!(f, "{}", buffer)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut source = String::from("Peter");
    let buffer = &source as *const String;
    let parser = Parser { buffer };

    source.push_str(" Pan");

    println!("{}", parser);
}
```